# Nth-Light Narrow LED, Linear Potentiometer and 12VDC power supply

Tags: led, potentiometer

Is it possible to connect Nth-Light Narrow LED Flexible Strip Light (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3683) directly to a 12VDC power supply and 10K Ohm Sliding Linear Potentiometer to control the light intensity?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! No, you need a driver (good) for it or a low ohmic potentiometer (inefficienct).

Comment: Thanks, any recommendations? What is a low ohmic potentiometer and why it is inefficienct?

Comment: Googling "12v led driver potentiometer dimmer" turned up 317 000 results. Look for 0-10 V control, which should interface niceley to your potentiometer. You ask what most people here woul classify as basic EE questions, so I would recommend you to buy a product for the task. If you want to dig deeper, I would recommend building your own 555 low side PWM dimmer. It should be a great first project to learn.

Comment: I wonder will this work: LED Strip Lights PWM Dimming Controller For LED Lights or Ribbon (Click [here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003L4KKF2/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=B003L4KKF2&linkCode=as2&tag=httpsmokedprb-20)), as your product power req. is 12V DC @ 65mA?